# Exemplo de objeto em tempo de execução em C#

Tags: c#, .net, objetos

Lendo um artigo apareceu o seguinte termo *runtime object* ou "objeto em tempo de execução". O que seria esse objeto? Seria uma instância de uma classe? Alguém pode passar algum exemplo?

A parte do artigo:

> The OO design process centers on use cases: a user performs standalone
>   tasks that have some useful outcome. (Logging on is not a use case
>   because it lacks a useful outcome in the problem domain. Drawing a
>   paycheck is a use case.) An OO system, then, implements the activities
>   needed to play out the various scenarios that comprise a use case. The
>   runtime objects that play out the use case do so by sending messages
>   to one another. Not all messages are equal, however. You haven't
>   accomplished much if you've just built a procedural program that uses
>   objects and classes.

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html

Mas o que eu queria saber mesmo é o que poderia ser um objeto em tempo de execução.

Comment: Toda certeza que não irá conseguir uma resposta, você tentou algo ? Se sim, [**edite**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/294881/edit) sua pergunta e coloque, e explique aonde está sua dúvida ou problema!

Comment: Eu não sei como é criar um objeto em tempo de execução, somente queria um exemplo disso, entendeu?

Comment: Acho que o meu problema é quanto a conceito. O que seria esse objeto? Seria uma instância de uma classe?

Comment: Cara, para eu não ficar criando muitas perguntas aqui, eu criei uma sala no chat, é a primeira vez que faço acesso por lá, não sei bem como funciona. Tem como eu convidar as pessoas ou simplesmente tenho que esperar que alguém entre?

Comment: Não sou muito familiarizado com criação de salas no chat, mas você pode tentar tirar a dúvida na sala [**Estouro de Pilha**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha). Você pode perguntar lá, e depois pode criar a pergunta aqui para ajudar outros usuários futuramente.

Comment: Criei esta sala https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76732/fazendo-a-analise-de-um-sistema acho que por aqui não posso pedir recomendações de livros, certo? Então pedi por lá.

Comment: Ainda não li o artigo, me baseei no trecho exibido na pergunta e suponho que os citados "runtime object" sejam objetos criados via padrão Object Factory ou Facade Pattern usando processos externos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sem ter mostrado o onde viu e o contexto não dá para ter certeza do que estava sendo falado, mas aparentemente é uma instância de uma classe.

Ou pode ser uma instância de algum tipo qualquer, independente de ser uma classe, mas parece ser sobre o objeto em si, ou seja, como ele é no momento que está executando.

Há possibilidade do termo ser usado por equívoco já que todo objeto é criado em tempo de execução. Talvez tenha sido usado o termo para reforçar a ideia ou porque usaram o termo objeto para o que seria a classe.

Comment: Adicionei o artigo na minha pergunta.

Comment: @HeyJoe então é isso mesmo, embora eu tenha achado o artigo um pouco vago e algumas coisas debatíveis.

Comment: Se o artigo fosse em português eu teria várias dúvidas, em inglês tenho mais ainda. Será que eu posso tentar traduzir o que eu conseguir e postar por aqui as dúvidas? Porque eu li que por aqui as dúvidas têm que ser específicas, não sei bem o quão específicas têm que ser.

Comment: Sim, pode, mas poste uma pergunta por dúvida diferente, a não ser que alguma delas seja muito inter-relacionada com outra e seja mais fácil responder junto. Dê contexto sempre. Pode usar uma referência de uma pergunta na outra.